# cx_Freeze-built application that uses the ssl module crashes on startup

Tags: python, cx-freeze

When starting the built .exe-file, the following message is printed:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 14, in run
    module.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "Application.py", line 8, in <module>
    from nats.aio.client import Client as NATS
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\nats\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .aio.client import Client as NATS
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\nats\aio\client.py", line 18, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 1):

The python _ssl.pyd requires some DLLs which need to be explicitly included in setup.py using the

```
import os.path
PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
build_exe_options = {"include_files" : [
    os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, "DLLs", "libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll"),
    os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, "DLLs", "libssl-1_1-x64.dll")]}

setup(  name = "Application",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "Application",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("app.py", base=None)])
```